# Is there something baked into Swift that decodes html or should I stick with using a dependency?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to get and decode html from a webpage that updates 1/day. I'm using URLSessions instead of Alamofire to get the html (As I understand during Swift 2, URLSessions could not do what Alamofire offered, but it can today in swift 4).

Similarly, I've seen the recommendations for Swiftsoup but before I use that - I wanted to find out if there is anything already baked in that can do this well?

Comment: There is no *baked-in* HTML parser in Swift.

Comment: got it. I will look into dependencies then. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

While not "baked into Swift", why not swing by GitHub and check out [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna).  Kanna(鉋) is an XML/HTML parser for cross-platform (macOS, iOS, tvOS, watchOS and Linux).  It likely has what you are looking for.

Comment: How does Kanna compare to Swiftsoup?

Comment: Sorry - I have not had the occasion to use Swiftsoup.  I was looking for a relatively intuitive HTML/XML parser and stumbled across Kanna.  It has integrated seamlessly into my toolkit and meets my (admittedly basic) needs.  if Switsoup works for you - super!

Comment: Do you happen to know why my question and your answer was downvoted?